# having an if statement inside an echo

Tags: php, database, if-statement, pdo

Can anyone tell me how I can include the if statement inside this echo?  I need my while statement to keep producing results and I need an efficient way to insert the if statement into this code after div class poster, can someone give any suggestions?

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo ' 
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
<div class="logo-logo"><h2>Question.</h2>
<div class="checkboxes">'.$row['formtype'].'
</div>

</div>
<div class="top-submit">
&#8220'. $row["actual_quote"] . '&#8221;
</div>
<div class="poster">- '. $row["poster"].'
if(isset($row3['voted'])){
if(isset($row3['ip'])){

    echo "You have already voted for this.";
}
}
else{

    echo "<form action = '' method = 'post'> <input type = 'submit' name = 'like' value = 'like'> <input type = 'submit' name = 'dislike' value = 'dislike'></form>";

}
<div class = "like">

</div>
<div class = "dislike">
</div>
</div>
<!-- use select to get the items to stay on the page-->

</div>
</div>
</div>
';
}
```

Comment: Just imagine if you couldn't echo the word "if" at all because it would think you were starting an if statement. Like others have said, you just need to break your echo up into a few echo statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not output your HTML using `echo`.  It makes the code harder to read and write due to you needing to constantly remember to not accidentally close your quote, not to mention it's a (small) waste of CPU cycles and memory.

Instead, break out of php to stream the content directly and only drop back into php for logic and echoing your variables.  In addition, you should use [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to encode what you're echoing out.

I assume `$row3` may be further up in your code so I left that alone for keys `voted` and `ip`.  You had an extra closing `div` in there which I removed.

```
<?php
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="submissions">
        <div class="logo-logo"><h2>Question.</h2>
            <div class="checkboxes"><?php echo htmlentities($row["formtype"]); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="top-submit">
            &#8220;<?php echo htmlentities($row["actual_quote"]); ?>&#8221;
        </div>
        <div class="poster">- <?php echo htmlentities($row["poster"]);
    if(isset($row3["voted"]) && isset($row3["ip"]))
    {
        echo "You have already voted for this.";
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
            <form action="" method="post"> <input type="submit" name="like" value="like" /> <input type="submit" name="dislike" value="dislike" /></form>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
            <div class = "like"></div>
            <div class = "dislike"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- use select to get the items to stay on the page-->

    </div>
</div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you would just break up the echo and include the if statement in between e.g.

```
echo 'sample content';
if($x=1) 'if statement content';
echo 'more sample content';
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to "finish" your first `echo` before the `if`, and start a new one afterwards.

Replace:

```
<div class="poster">- '. $row["poster"].'
```

with:

```
<div class="poster">- '. $row["poster"];
```

And

```
<div class = "like">
```

with:

```
echo '<div class = "like">
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (approach) would be to use Ternary operator this way:

```
echo ('if statement') ? 'value on true' : 'value on false';
```

But it will reduce readability if you don't have short statement and values to echo, so use it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Take your HTML out of your PHP logic and into a separate template file:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="submissions">
        <div class="logo-logo">
            <h2>Question.</h2>

            <div class="checkboxes">
                <?php echo $row['formtype']; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="top-submit">
            &#8220<?php echo $row["actual_quote"]; ?>&#8221;
        </div>

        <div class="poster">
            - <?php echo $row["poster"]; ?>
            <?php echo if(isset($row3['voted'])): ?>
                <?php echo if(isset($row3['ip'])): ?>
                    You have already voted for this.
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <form action = '' method = 'post'> <input type = 'submit' name = 'like' value = 'like'>
                    <input type = 'submit' name = 'dislike' value = 'dislike'>
                </form>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class = "like">

            </div>

            <div class = "dislike">

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- use select to get the items to stay on the page-->

    </div>
</div>
```

Then include it from your while loop:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   include __DIR__ . "/form.template.phtml";
}
```

[Alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)